# Ckeditor how to change button text

Tags: django, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, django-ckeditor

My django site uses the image upload feature. I want to change the `send it to the server` button text to `upload`

I have checked what seems like every source file but I cannot filed a reference to button.
How would I go about changing it.

I found [this posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352812/ckeditor-change-button-text) trying to do the same thing but it is very old

[image]

Update:

I dug through what seems like every file but I cannot find the reference to `send it to the server` not sure what to do at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Probably too late for your situation, but posting anyway in case others needs a solution in the future (as I just did today):

I found a solution using CKEDITOR this way:

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev)
            {
                var dialogName = ev.data.name;
                var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
                if (dialogName == 'image')
                {
                    //console.log(dialogDefinition);
                    dialogDefinition.contents[2].elements[1].label = 'upload';
                }
    });
```

You can use the commented out `console.log(dialogDefinition)` to see the array positions of everything in the dialog window. In short, the contents represents the tabs (in which [2] is the upload tab) and elements represents labels, buttons etc inside each tab.

Comment: Going to give this a try thank you!

Comment: No problem, hope it works for you! Let me know if you run into any issues and I'll be happy to follow up on it.

Comment: Did you put this code in the `config.js` file?

Comment: My project is a Laravel project and not Django, but ought to be the same. 
I placed it inside the view in a <script> tag. Should be possible in virtually any framework, just place it where you would usually write Javascript for your application.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately couldn't get the code working, did you use this for the `send to server btn`?

Comment: I did. Also used it to change a few other things - can be used for anything in the window.  
Make sure the event is triggered when opening the window. Can uncomment the console.log part, and see if it shows up in the console. 
If it does not, you might've added the script in the wrong location in your project.